# Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Loader::libary() in EE_Pagination.php

Tags: pagination

I receive this error from a new installation, 2.8.0

I have only a channel and a template.

If I display a single item, all works fine, if I use pagination, receive this error.

My code is very simple, this is my first site in ee.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog"
    limit="10"
    paginate="bottom"
}

    {title}

    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's a spelling issue in "libary" should be "library"

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20172

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the bug report. Fixed the error for me!